# How to debug mysterious OS issue

Tags: debian, data-transfer

I've had a new computer for less than a year (4cpus intel I5, 32GB ram, 250GB SSD). I fresh installed Debian 10. I've been extremely frugal with what I install - keep the bloat to a minimum so I can keep the new OS fast.

Over the past few days I've noticed a strange pattern. I have these very large files (compressed with zst) that I some times need to decompress. They are about 1GB compressed and decompress to around 15GB (It's not a herculean task, but certainly not negligible for my system). I decompress them using `zstd -cd 20201216.zst > 20201216.log`. While running, `zstd` prints the progress so far. I've noticed that it some times stops for 20-30 seconds, and then resumes. At first I thought that I had accidentally fired off more than one task and some sort of contention was causing this. But checking `htop` you can see there's very little going on the OS at the same time (loads of free RAM, all 4 cpus around 1%). Additionally I checked `iotop` and I see that when `zstd` says it's working, `iotop` shows very large 100s MB/s read and write. When `zstd` is making no progress, `iotop` shows 0B/s read and write. So the problem is neither CPU contention nor disk contention.

Some times, but rarely, the whole system freezes while this is happening. Most of the times I can use the system normally while `zstd` is freezing.

What else should I look at debug this problem?

EDIT: I've run smartctl, below is the report. I don't know how to interpret this yet, looking into it.

```
smartctl 6.6 2017-11-05 r4594 [x86_64-linux-4.19.0-9-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-17, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     VENO SCORP SSD 240GB
Serial Number:    GSDMC206010008
Firmware Version: XKR905
User Capacity:    240,057,409,536 bytes [240 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Dec 20 17:36:11 2020 GMT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00)     Offline data collection activity
                                    was never started.
                                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0)     The previous self-test routine completed
                                    without error or no self-test has ever
                                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:            (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                        (0x11) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                    command.
                                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                                    Self-test supported.
                                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                    No Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0002)     Does not save SMART data before
                                    entering power-saving mode.
                                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01)     Error logging supported.
                                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  10) minutes.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       816
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       138
160 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
161 Unknown_Attribute       0x0033   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       100
163 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       17
164 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       9546
165 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       30
166 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       3
167 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       13
168 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       1500
169 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       100
175 Program_Fail_Count_Chip 0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
176 Erase_Fail_Count_Chip   0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
178 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Chip  0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       27
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       40
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       7896
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
232 Available_Reservd_Space 0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       100
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0030   100   100   050    Old_age   Offline      -       19968
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0030   100   100   050    Old_age   Offline      -       5880
245 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       25733

SMART Error Log Version: 1
Warning: ATA error count 0 inconsistent with error log pointer 4

ATA Error Count: 0
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error -4 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 0 hours (0 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  b0 d0 01 00 4f c2 00 08      00:00:00.000  SMART READ DATA
  b0 d1 01 01 4f c2 00 08      00:00:00.000  SMART READ ATTRIBUTE THRESHOLDS [OBS-4]
  b0 da 00 00 4f c2 00 08      00:00:00.000  SMART RETURN STATUS
  b0 d5 01 00 4f c2 00 08      00:00:00.000  SMART READ LOG
  b0 d5 01 01 4f c2 00 08      00:00:00.000  SMART READ LOG

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported
```

Comment: Have you checked your disk for SMART errors?

Comment: @DavidPostill I didn't know such thing existed, found a recommendation to run `smartctl`, I've run and edited my original post to include the report. I don't know how to interpret yet, so if you see something that jumps at you let me know. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Nothing jumps out

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check your HDD/SSD for errors in linux terminal I recomend using HDSentinel for Linux instead of smartctl because the result is easier to read...

[HDSentinel for Linux](https://www.hdsentinel.com/hdslin/hdsentinel-018c-x64.gz)

Just donwnload, unzip to /usr/bin, chmod to 755 and run as root

sudo hdsentinel -dev /dev/sda (or replace sda with your drive name)

Comment: I can't seem to find the license for this software...?

Comment: The linux version of hdsentinel is free!

Comment: What's the license though?